# How can I get the text out of a <textarea> tag in Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I know nothing about HTML and I am learning Android `WebView`.

In my App, it displays a HTML file with `WebView`. In the html there is a line:

```
<textarea  cols=""  id="system_text" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0px; width:300px; height:120px;"></textarea>
```

When the user click a button, I should store the user input somewhere. But I don't know how can I extract the text. I know how to get text from `EditText`, but I have no idea with `WebView`. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) its an open source html parser then you can write like this `String my_text = getElementByTagName("textarea").text();`